# Laravel API Authentication for CURL

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl

I'm building an API which will allow webshops to create an order (using CURL for now).

Now I've been looking into OAuth2 but I'm confused as to what a good method is? It all seems overkill.

> What would be the easiest way to Authenticate a person in Laravel so they can get to the api.php routes?

#### I've tried

- OAuth2 with Client but I have to redirect first and then get the access token, but that's not possible in CURL, right?

Comment: '.... right?' no , it's possible , However you may need to take a look at JWT authentication too.

Answer (score 0):

check this library  to use jwt tokens
https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Answer (score 0):

You can try **JWT (JSON Web Token)** for authenticate API, [Click here](https://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs) to read JSON Web Token Tutorial with laravel & angular.